# delete UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I was wondering if it's possible to remove empty cells (empty = cells with no textLabel) after all the cells are created in a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have empty cells?  Are you using a consistent technique to control both the number of cells in your table and the content of those cells?

If you're using a UITableViewController, then your controller is automatically declared as the tableview's datasource.  If you're using a UIViewController, then you'll declare it as comforming to the UITableViewDataSource protocol (and connect it up in Interface Builder).

Either way, as the tableview's datasource, your controller is required to implement two methods:
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Presumably you're providing the data for the tableview with an array or other means inside -tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  Inside this method the cell's label will be set from an entry in your array.  And inside tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: you'll be doing something like [myArray count] to return the number of cells.  tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called as many times as you tell it to (dictated by what you provide in tableview:numberOfRowsInSection:).  If the datasource array changes, and you'd like to reflect the changes in your tableview, then you can call

```
[self.tableview reloadData];  //if inside a UITableViewController

[self.myTableViewOutlet reloadData];  //if inside a UIViewController
```

Note that reloadData reloads the entire tableview, so in some cases this may be computationally expensive.  In this case, instead of calling reloadData you can focus on individual rows with the method: deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: (see [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: hey matt, I found the problem, it was a library that I was using to load the images asynchronously that caused the cells to be empty. since you have already answered a few questions I have posted here, you are semi familiar with what I am doing :) , now I am facing an issue with when I logout a user and then login with another user, the problem is that the UITableView doesnt get refreshed to fetch the new data for the new user eventhough the ID of the user is updated and I have put a reloadData in viewdidload(), any idea why?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some of your code.  You could post your code in a new question.  Formulating a well structured question with parts of your code included is often a good way to think through the problem too.  In the mean time, to debug the problem yourself, you should put NSLog(@"some text here"); statements in your tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method and in your viewDidLoad method.  This will help you see when methods are being called or if they're not.

Comment: thanks for the reply, found a solution... for some reason it caches the UIView when you use tabBar controller, so I just used the function viewWillAppear() to update the UIView. but thanks again

Comment: That's right, the view is left in memory for speed purposes.  Therefore viewDidLoad is often only called once.  It might be called later if a memory warning situation forces it to unload.  Great, viewWillAppear is a good place for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As the app delegate, you are responsible for providing cells.  It is your responsibility to return every cell, and the number of cells in the table.  Therefore as the app delegate you should have a means (be it by NSMutableArray or otherwise) to mutate the data that you return to the table view.

Comment: The 'app delegate' should have little to do with a view controller's tableview.  Did you mean the tableview delegate and datasource?